# Embedded Linux Kernel and Desktop Linux Kernel Difference

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, embedded-linux

Is there difference between embedded linux kernel and desktop linux kernel?

I think there is a one linux kernel support all devices(arm,arm64,x86/x64 etc.), and developers make distribute like debian(for desktop)/raspian(for embedded), arch/archarm. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there is one official kernel for different architectures at kernel.org

There may be forks with special hardware handling, additional drivers, etc. for specific customers (hardware suppliers like Samsung)

But your assumption is 90% true ;)

Comment: This is less true in practice than in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Linux kernel source is the same for an embedded device vs. a desktop computer (or server). But when configuring a Linux kernel before compiling, we specify the architecture type we want to run the kernel on. We do so using an environment variable called ARCH.

Also note that the Linux kernel configuration may vary for a Linux server and an embedded Linux device (which may has different priorities in terms of real-time responsiveness, power saving, ...)

Of course some of the embedded Linux board/chip vendors may use their own repository.

Answer (score 0):

linux kernel is same for desktop or embedded though for embedded application, developer can customize it with configuration to make it suitable for specific embedded application or hardware. Goal is to create kernel with only essential features that are required for embedded application for target and that means every embedded product or hw can have their customized kernel image. Apart from this, even userspace applications are also selected like some apps like busybox instead of full fledged shell are used for embedded applications. Take a look at intro of yocto distribution. In case of architecture, linux kernel supports many   processor architectures like arm, mips, powerpc though that essentially does not classify as embedded application and you can have linux kernel as general purpose use with these non-x86 architectures as well. Some platforms like coldfire processor use no mmu and specifically used in embedded appplications and they have their uclinux distribution though i am not sure if nommu is part of today's linux kernel or given as separate patch for uclinux. There are some examples like real time support was separate patch for linux kernel until it was included in kernel and some embedded applications prefer to distribute those patches.